# Xml Root.add value with Special Character( :)

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have an XML file 
which is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<urlset >

</urlset>
```

I'm trying to add an XElement with special characters (:) code behind

```
string xmlpath = @"~/myxml.xml";
string path = Server.MapPath(xmlpath);
string title="SomeString"
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
XElement root = new XElement("url");
root.Add(new XElement("Video:title", "title"));//here is the problem i have Special char (:) which not allowed
doc.Element("urlset").Add(root);
```

also i can't use &qoute; becuse it's contniue special char & Please i need help if any one can help i would be thankful thanks a lot for your time guys and thank a lot for giving time to read my queation

Comment: You cannot have a node named `<Video:title>`.  That colon is reserved for namespaces.

Comment: Element or node, they're the same thing.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use the colon there?  Why not switch it to a dash?

Comment: thx a lot for your answer and your time

Comment: it's for google sitemap they need it like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to add an XElement with special characters (:) code behind

Try using a `XmlDocument` which will allow creating an `XmlElement` with specified name and namespace.

```
 string xmlpath = @"~/myxml.xml";
 string path = Server.MapPath(xmlpath);
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

 doc.Load(path);
 var mainRoot = doc.DocumentElement; //urlset element
 var urlRoot = doc.CreateElement("url"); //create url element
 urlRoot.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Video:title","title")); //add element to the url element
 mainRoot.AppendChild(urlRoot); // add this new element to the main root of urlset
```

Example Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<urlset>
  <url>
    <Video:title xmlns:Video="title" />
  </url>
</urlset>
```

Or if you just want a `Video` node with namespace of `title`...

```
 urlRoot.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Video","title"));
```

The output of this above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<urlset>
  <url>
    <Video xmlns="title"/>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

Please let me know if this isn't your expected output.

Comment: thx a lot! that's what i was looking for acutely I'm very glad and thankful for your help

Comment: @Darwiesh Mustafa If the answer was helpful to you, you should accept it by clicking the check-mark https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers